# Stack around the variable 'userStr' was corrupted (C)

Tags: c, runtime-error, automaton

I've tried looking this up, and every single one seems to have a completely different answer.

I have this REPL function that compares a user's string input to a deterministic finite automaton (DFA), and that runs perfectly fine.

```
void REPL(DFA userDFA)
{
    char userStr[] = {'0'};
    printf("\nWhat string would you like to use?\n");
    scanf("%s", userStr);
    if (DFA_execute(userDFA, userStr))
        printf("\nAccepted\n");
    else
        printf("\nRejected\n");
} //program crashes right here

int main(void){...}
```

However, as soon as it reaches the end of the function, the program crashes and gives me the following error:

`Run-Time Check Failure #2 - Stack around the variable 'userStr' was corrupted.`

Comment: `char userStr[] = {'0'};` This defines a 1-char long array. `scanf("%s", userStr);` This reads a user-entered string (plus the nul-terminator) into the same array, which overruns it and corrupts the stack.

Comment: To be honest, you seem to have skipped a crucial part of your text-book, tutorial or class. Either that or you need to find new teaching resources.

Comment: To emphasize what others have been saying: `char userStr[] = {'0'};` is equal to `char userStr[1] = {'0'};`

Comment: It's worth nothing that C does not, and will never allocate memory unless you ask it to either implicitly or explicitly. This asks for one byte, and that's all you get. If you need more, you need to ask, like `char userStr[1024]`. C strings and how to manipulate them is a very important, yet often somewhat confusing part of the C language, you need to know about pointers, arrays, and memory allocation, so be sure you've got a handle on that before getting tangled up in other things.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
char userStr[] = {'0'};
```

This means that `userStr` can only hold a single value; including the terminator. You haven't specified the size, so it looked at what you had in the `{}`. You only have a single element in there, so that's what size it used. Writing off the end of the array though into the memory that comes after it will corrupt the stack (because it's holding important stuff, like return addresses and other data).

Specify the size to allow it to hold more:

```
char userStr[100] = {'0'};
```

This is giving it an arbitrary size of 100 long. You may need to give it a larger size, or use dynamic memory allocation (`malloc` and the like) to allocate to a size that's known at runtime.